# Angular 4 - Filter for date column in md table not working

Tags: angular

Could you please help me how to filter the date column in md-table.

Usually when i enter the date in filter text box, the result is not filtered, but for other columns filter is working as expected.

Below is the stackblitz link
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkkvbd

Comment: When you say new Date(2018, 11, 24), the actual value is Mon Dec 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200, so if you type Mon Dec 24 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 in the filter it works :)

Comment: How to handle this situation as I need to use Date Pipe

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to filter by eg.

1. 12/24/2018
2. 12/24
3. 24
4. 2018
5. and similar - in general, by partial date with given 'MM/dd/yyyy' format

You need to manually filter the data using required date format

```
  pipe: DatePipe;

  constructor() {
    this.pipe = new DatePipe('en');
    console.log(this.dataSource.filterPredicate);
    const defaultPredicate=this.dataSource.filterPredicate;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>{
      const formatted=this.pipe.transform(data.created,'MM/dd/yyyy');
      return formatted.indexOf(filter) >= 0 || defaultPredicate(data,filter) ;
    }
  }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkkvbd-tpsnrj?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

This filters by all columns including date column.

This all could be avoided if you would use formatted date (thus string) as data in your table model (datasource) insteed of date. It would work out of the box like it works for weight column.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will take a look.

Comment: Hi Antonios, actually I added in the same way that you said date as string table model, but sorting is not working for the date column.

Comment: Have you seen my stackblitz? it works there. And no you did not, you are using pipe

Answer (score 0):

The date shown in the table is not the actual value. You use the `date` pipe. The filtering is working with the original value.

Comment: I need to use date pipe, Can not we filter if we use pipes?

Comment: You can change the original data to this format without the date pipe. You can also try to make a custom filter that filters according to the shown format (maybe in the applyFilter function).